# ios localization Alert

Tags: ios, localization

i'm having a problem with the localizable.string file

to change the language of the label or button i have no problem i change it on the storyboard string without problem but when i have an alert to show i have to use the NSLocalizedString

i've created the localizable.strings file and clicked on the localize button to choose all the language that i needed in this file i've put the key i need to translate

for example in the french file

```
"FIELDS_MANDATORY" = "Tout les champs sont obligatoire";
```

which is called in the method

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
message:NSLocalizedString(@"FIELDS_MANDATORY", @"Message") 
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
```

but when i launch the simulator it just show me "FIELDS_MANDATORY"

any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

You've added it in correctly but not given file name  properly,

Localized filename should always be named `Localizable.strings`, and that file is within the particular language folder, for English, `en.lproj` and for French `fr.lproj` like wise.

Other than your code looks good.